# Problem related to Cyclotomic Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I'm trying to show that if $p$ is prime, then $$x^{p-1}-x^{p-2}+x^{p-3}-...-x+1$$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I don't have an idea of how to start. I know the $p^{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to do this starts as follows: Rewrite the polynomial as $\frac{x^p+1}{x+1}$ and substitute $x-1$ for $x$. See if you can get anywhere with that.

If you give up, a similar result is proved [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Cyclotomic_polynomials)

Comment: I got it, thanks!

Comment: Answer at the following link was useful. http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/16.pdf